# Why does “U0001f60e” come up in various online text?

Tags: html, unicode

I’ve seen this a worrying number of times as of late, people will write a comment and it'll end in `U0001f60e` or I’ll just be reading an article and `U0001f60e` appears in it at seemingly random points.

I can only speculate this is some sort of Unicode decoding thing, but I can’t seem to find any relevant information on this weird set of characters.

It appears to me on Firefox/Chrome/IE, and it’s just slightly worrying.

Comment: Please provide specific examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`U+1F60E` is [smiling face with sunglasses](http://www.charbase.com/1f60e-unicode-smiling-face-with-sunglasses) Unicode character which looks like this:

[image]

Either your browser cannot display it, or it is incorrectly *escaped* on the actual web page you are having issues with.